# How to print/show only two decimals (javascript/CSS/HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a lot of answers to this question but I have no idea which is the best answer or where to add it..

This is the code:

```
                             // HTML //
 <html>

 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

 var v1 = 0;
 var v2 = 0;

 var answer = 0;

 function calculate () {

 answer = v1 / v2;

 var elem;
 elem = document.getElementById("v1");
 elem.value = v1;
 elem = document.getElementById("v2");
 elem.value = v2;

 elem = document.getElementById("answer");
 elem.value = answer;

 }

 function setValue(elem) {
 var val = 0.0;
 if (elem.value != "") {
 val = parseFloat(elem.value);
 }
 else {
 val = 0.0;
 }
 switch (elem.id) {
 case "v1": v1 = val; break;
 case "v2": v2 = val; break;
 }
 calculate();
 }
 </script>

 [..]

 </head>
 [...]
```

and

```
                              // HTML //

[...]

<form>
<input type="text" id="v1" onKeyUp="javascript: setValue(this);">
<input type="text" id="v2" onKeyUp="javascript: setValue(this);">
<input type="text" id="answer" readonly>
</form>

[...]
```

Now, what would make the result show or print (I don`t know which one is correct) only 2 decimals and where should that be placed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toFixed(2)`

```
(parseFloat(elem.value)).toFixed(2);
```

The problem with your code is you are **attempting to set the value of the current textbox** where you **seem to be typing** .. So if you hit backspace , it is again overwritten **and goes into a infinite loop..**

You seem to have written a lot of code to get done a trivial task..

Move your inline javascript and attach the events in the script itself..

I have made a few modifications to your code..

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="v1" value="0.00">
<input type="text" id="v2" value="0.00">
<input type="text" id="answer" readonly>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for(var i =0;i< elem.length ; i++){
     elem[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(){
          setValue(this); 
     });
     elem[i].addEventListener("blur", function(){
          setCurrentValue(this); 
     });
}

function setCurrentValue(elem){
    elem.value = parseFloat(elem.value).toFixed(2);
}

function calculate(v1,v2) {
    answer = v2 == 0 ? 0 : (v1/v2);
    var elem = document.getElementById("answer");
    elem.value = parseFloat(answer).toFixed(2);;

}

function setValue(elem) {
    var v1 = document.getElementById('v1').value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById('v2').value;
    v1 = v1 == '' ? 0 : parseFloat(v1);
    v2 = v2 == '' ? 0 : parseFloat(v2);
    calculate(v1,v2);
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ayM5s/)**

Comment: thanks but that only changes the input area (v1 and v2) which is better as it is. To make sure I did it right.. I added `val = (parseFloat(elem.value)).toFixed(2);` instead of  `val = parseFloat(elem.value);` and, also :S, I have no idea why it keeps refreshing the input fields, I can`t even type 11.1, I have to type 111 and then tap left arrow to add the dot.

Comment: Thank you so much. It will take some time before I understand it.. at the moment it is not calculating anything, as soon as I refresh the page it waits for about 1 second (the answer field) and after that NaN appears and it`s not changing after I add the input.. but I`m pretty sure I did something wrong. Thanks a lot.